# Do I win league medals if I don't participate?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have some work this month, for that I'm not sure if I can participate in clash of clans league or not.

1. If I don't participate, can I win league medals or not?
2. Can I win these medals if I replace someone in a day?
3. Can we both win, or just one of us?
4. Can you please explain, how these medals can be won?

Answer (score 1):

From clash of clans wiki
https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Clan_War_Leagues
You can get at least 20% of the league medals that your clan has won if you are in the roster,even though you are not in any war.